# Processing stdin line by line

Tags: node.js, stream, pipe

I'm using [`process.stdin.read()`](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdin) to process lines of text by handling `readable` event. In my case it returns either one line at a time or all the input text.

Is this reliable? In other words, which is the possibility that it will return half of the line?

The key requirement is to process as soon as possible, not waiting while all the input data is collected.

Comment: Do you see the newlines in the data you read?

Comment: @JohnZwinck Yes, if I feed ordinary file it returns all the data with one call, including newlines. The question is will it work the same way with different conditions. For example if lines would be much longer or with long delays.

Comment: Can't you check by simply looking for newlines at the end of each read?  If you see data with no trailing newline, you need to wait?

Comment: @JohnZwinck Indeed. I should've guessed. However interesting to know how it works in theory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at `event-stream`'s `split. It's made to handle line based buffering.

https://github.com/dominictarr/event-stream#simple-example

```
  var es = require('event-stream')
  var inspect = require('util').inspect

  process.stdin                        //connect streams together with `pipe`
    .pipe(es.split())                  //split stream to break on newlines
    .pipe(es.map(function (data, cb) { //turn this async function into a stream
      cb(null
        , inspect(JSON.parse(data)))   //render it nicely
    }))
    .pipe(process.stdout)              // pipe it to stdout !
```